# In Angular, is there a reason not to list module dependencies with the module declaration?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

In all the tutorials and examples I've read regarding Angularjs, they all define modules with an empty list as the second parameter:

```
angular.module('myModule', []);
```

I understand that the presence of the second parameter is required to create a new module, but I don't understand why there are never any elements in the list.  The document for angular.module says nothing about what the contents of the list would represent.

However, from defining my app module I understand the list represents modules upon which the new module depends - so why is it always empty for app sub-modules?  For example, in my own project I've got a users module upon which my app depends:

```
/* app.js */
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router',
    'myApp.system',
    'myApp.users'
]);

angular.module('myApp.system', []);
angular.module('myApp.users', []);
```

When I finally got around to learning how to unit test using karma and jasmine, I spent hours trying to figure out this error message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.users due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider
        at /Users/matt/Development/myApp/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3556
        at getService (/Users/matt/Development/myApp/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3683)
        at invoke (/Users/matt/Development/myApp/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3710)
        at /Users/matt/myApp/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3639
```

Eventually I found two things that would fix this problem - either I could load module dependencies in the test code, or I could add the dependencies to the empty list in the users module declaration:

```
/* UserControllerTest.js */
describe('UserCtrl', function () {

    var $rootScope,
        $scope,
        controller;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('ui.router');
        module('myApp.system');
        module('ngResource');
        module('myApp.users');

        inject(function ($injector) {
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $injector.get('$controller')('UserCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
        });
    });

    it('should work', function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

});
```

Or:

```
/* app.js */
...
angular.module('myApp.users', [
    'ngResource',
    'ui.router',
    'mean.system'
]);
```

Is there some reason I wouldn't want to do the latter?  Why is it that I never see that in docs and tutorials - would it prevent me from being able to mock those dependencies in testing?

Why is it that I don't need the latter sub-module definition for regular operation of my app?  I do have a series of 'injection locals' specified for UserCtrl - why isn't that sufficient for the unit test?

Comment: The second approach makes more sense to me, and it is what I do in my code. You are explicitly telling whomever uses the code after you that these are the dependencies of that module. This makes the code a little clearer.

Comment: @Sobieck00 could it be that the examples I've seen are trivial, and their modules don't have dependencies?

Comment: It could be, but I'm really not aware of what other people in the community are doing. I'll try to dig around tomorrow and answer this question with examples... If I have time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of modules is to encapsulate self-contained parts of code (e.g. a reusable widget, code tgst implements a specific feature etc). In general, it is a good practice to have each module declare the dependencies it relies upon.

If not, then the module relies on the modules thst require it to declare those dependencies, which messes "self-containment", hurts testability and reusability and introduces a bunch if potential future bugs.

That said, there doesn't seem to be a reason not to declare dependencies with each module. (And no, it will not prevent you from mocking the dependencies in unit tests.) Of cource, as one would expect, each module is loaded once even if it is required by several modules.

The API reference is indeed not very detailed about `angular.module`, but the **[Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)** has a more extensive description.

E.g., quoting the "Dependencies" section:

> Modules can list other modules as their dependencies. Depending on a module implies that required module needs to be loaded before the requiring module is loaded. In other words the configuration blocks of the required modules execute before the configuration blocks of the requiring module. The same is true for the run blocks. **Each module can only be loaded once, even if multiple other modules require it**.

Comment: As I suspected, the examples and tutorials I've read are not sufficiently large to have dependencies for modules (or are small enough that they can get away without listing them, since by chance they're already loaded.)